# How to clear the activity stack in Android

Tags: android

I have the following application flow in my Android app,

Login->Home->screen1->screen2->screen3->screen4-> logout

In the screen4 I have a log out button, which allows the user to logout from the application and re-login. When I re-login to the app, the previous data is still shown. Is there a way to start the application fresh when the user logs out from the app?

NOTE: all the above activities launch mode set to "single task",

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See if that helps - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
(This and other flags)

Comment: thx Kiril for quik reply i tried the below code but no luck.public void signOutHandler(View view) {
Intent i = new Intent(this,login.class);
  i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  startActivity(i);

 }

Comment: well i tried the above method on the log out button onclick event,may be i have did it wrong way,can you tell me exactly where i should define that attribute?

Answer (score 2):

You could set a static flag when the user clicks `logout` and in each activity check that flag in onResume() and if it's set call `finish()`. That's kind of hacky though.

Answer (score 0):

Well I dont know it its that what you want but can finishing activity before starting another and storing login in Application Context can help?

Answer (score -1):

Configure this for your activity in AndroidManifest.xml. The attribute is [android:clearTaskOnLaunch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear).

Comment: i think this attribute will be useful when user click on the HOME or back button on the phone,in my case i need to use the button onClick event to clear the stack.